# Excel VBA Sigma Formula

Tags: excel, vba, math, excel-formula, algebra

I tried to write this formula excel vba what is my wrong

```
For i = 1 To (N - 1)
    H = H + N- (i / (N) ^ P)
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The loop is only for what is behind the sum sign `Σ` and the `N - Σ` must be calculated **after** the loop. Also you need to place the perenthesis correctly:

```
Public Function H(ByVal N As Long, ByVal P As Double) As Double
    'Calculate the sum Σ
    Dim S As Double 'result of the sum Σ
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To (N - 1)
        S = S + ((i / N) ^ P)
    Next

    'Then calculate the rest
    H = N - S
End Function
```

Comment: @ahmetSERT The loop is only the part behind the minus sign in the formula you show in the image. So only the sum part is done in the loop and and saved in the variable `S`. So for the complete formula the left part of the minus sign is missing therefore we need to calculate `N - S` and save that into `H`. Did that help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a formula to do it:

```
=B1 -SUMPRODUCT((ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1-1))/B1)^B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution using `ROW()`.

Comment: =$J3-sumproduct((power(row(INDIRECT("1:"&$J3-1))/$J3;N$2))) 

in normal excel i did it like this but vba it is problem

Answer (score 0):

For caulations, VBA follows operator precedence, so we should carefully use parentheses around the calculations in order to change the predence of operators. Absence of parentheses at the right place in the above caluclations could be the reason of unexpected result. Please refer to the link below to see the operator precendence:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence